# When working deep in multiple levels of directories how does one assign a variable with the exact path each file needs to be found and accessed?

Tags: php, filepath, directory-structure, document-root

This has always been a problem for me. I have never learned the proper way to do this.

I am now working on a website where using things like ../../ will not long work. I need to somehow create a variable or resource or constant so that I can call the path from root to the file like this.
JUST AN EXAMPLE

```
link="<?php ROOT_PATH . "/footer.php" ?>"
```

and this would be:

```
link="inc/assets/directory1/directory2/footer.php"
```

But I would also need to be able to use the same variable or constant without changing its value and it will work no matter what directory the file is in or how many levels deep it is.

The file could be 7 folder deep in the directory structure but I still need it to work.

I've been people up here use similar techniques with DOCUMENT_ROOT. But I've yet to be able to get that one to work for me the way i need it to.

I am so STUCK. PLEASE! lol. Any help would be great, thanks!

NOTE: Before I start getting to far into this project and writing out all these paths by hand I need to wait till a new method has become available.

UPADATE: I simply wan to beable to point to any file in the file/directory structure no matter how many dirs deep it is using just one path variable or constant. there has got to be a wy to define the path of a iel  up to a given point and just use that for all your files. Wordpress must do this.

UPDATE: Two more hours digging through pills of internet crap and I can not find my solution. It seems if no one can just give me the answer I'm going to have to take an entire class in server technologies.

Comment: You wouldn't want to save the php echo in the variable, just the path you need. Probably simpler to create a constant anyway: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

Comment: yeah I know I was just trying to make an example. I don't know how it's done.

Comment: I understand constants mate. I need a function or sever function, anything that will do what I need.If I could do it myself I would obviously have made it and no need to look t constants. but thanks.

Comment: So what you are asking for is a constant or variable that you can use like this `$MYPATH."footer.php"` and have it find footer.php regardless of whether the file is in your root folder or a subfolder x levels deep? That is simply not going to happen unless you a. Program it yourself or find a 3rd party library that does it for you AND b. Only have each file name appear once in your entire folder structure.

Comment: Yeah basically. There has t be a simple function that I can put in front of the file name that will give the absolute file path.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you possible show me in an answer, so it's formatted better, how this is done?

Comment: Example : http://pastebin.com/XWN9pnLt. I actually have a complete 'applcation bootstrap' that sets up different environments i.e. testing,  logging and autoloader. Namespaces, etc. All based off `app_home_root` and some config files.

Comment: Regarding your update: SunKnight0 has the right idea. There's no "one size fits all" solution for this, especially since we don't know the "true" structure of your application. Like that user said, you'll either need to write something custom or find a package and then edit it until it works for your app. And your write, I'm sure WP does that - most likely with a custom "walker". Go take a look how they do it, and give it a go. Ryan's pastebin is a good simple example too.

Comment: If you are using wordpress, try using `<?php echo get_template_directory(); ?>` Documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory
Other than that, as the others said, you can't just expect there to be a php function that searches for a file of your choosing, unless you write one yourself.

Comment: I think you are getting a little confused and frustrated with what is fairly easy once you understand what is happening. The issue is that you should not use relative file paths anywhere in your PHP scripts. Why? because they are always based on the **'current working directory'** which is not always the same as __DIR__ in PHP scripts! This confuses people. But you can use 'relative directories' in absolute file paths! i.e. `include __DIR__ .'/../another.php';`  will include the file from the parent directory of this file - **it is an absolute filepath** but has a relative path as part of it.

Comment: **Absolute paths never use the 'current working directory'**. There are lots of articles and answer about this but I cannot find a good one that describe how to use the PHP file functions as well. Still: maybe interesting? http://www.geeksengine.com/article/absolute-relative-path.html. Also: http://yagudaev.com/posts/resolving-php-relative-path-problem/ but use `__DIR__` instead of `dirname()`. If you want more details then I will put a document together with some code to explain it all. I am rather familiar with it as I work on windows but host on linux ;-/

Comment: There are similar issues with relative and absolute URL's so always use absolute ones. i.e they always start with a '/' and are based on `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.